# Sum not adding up on list that exceeds threshold

Tags: list, list-view, list-view-threshold

I have a list that has about 10,000 items.  There are 5 locations each with 2000 items.  Each item has a qty of 1 so the Sum of the location should be 2000.  When I look at the Sum however it shows varying numbers.  One location has 248, another 1000, and another 2. I understand it is because I exceed the threshold limit of 5000.  I have indexed the location column, and then created a view that filters to that location (now should be under the 5,000 limit) however even on the "filtered view" I still show the same number in this case the 248 instead of the 2000.  I also see the "Displaying only the newest results below.  To view all results, narrow your query by adding a filter."  How do I get it to show the sum of 2000?